# Ubuntu EC2 compatible kernels

Tags: server, kernel, cloud, amazon-ec2, aws

I am trying to create an Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit AMI with the paravirtual type of virtualization. I have not had problems with the hvm virtualization.
I can't figure out what kernel I need to use. For the AMI regisrtation I use us-east-1 aki-919dcaf8 pv-grub-hd0_1.04-x86_64.gz. What kernel that supports pv-grub is supposed to be installed on the base Ubuntu machine? I have found [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-image-virtual) and tried linux-image-virtual for saucy, installed this package and it relies on the generic kernel. In [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernalTeam/EC2Kernel) article some ec2 kernels are mentioned but I was unable to install them, there are some dependency issues and those kernels are quite old.
Ubuntu package search for "linux-image-ec2" gives this result: lucid (10.04LTS) (kernel): Linux kernel image for ec2 machines 2.6.32.366.47 [security]: amd64 i386.
All my attempts failed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Ubuntu Amazon EC2 AMI locator](https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/) to find a suitable AMI and AKI